# twitter statuses/destroy not executing in mocha/chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, twitter, mocha.js

I'm trying to clean up after a node/twitter route test in node, and when placing my post request to delete the tweet in my after clause, it does not execute and the twitter API does not throw an error either...

I'm thinking that it might be the way I'm passing in the tweet ID and not using function scope properly. For those unfamiliar, I'm using the [Twitter module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) for node.js:

```
describe( "The nodeshell's /tweet route", function() {
  // Logic to run before each test
  var tid = "";

  before( function( done ) {
    startServer( done );
  });

  // Logic to run after each test
  after( function( done ) {
    client.post('statuses/destroy/:id', {id: tid}, function(error, params, response){
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      }
    });

    stopServer(done);
  });

  it( 'should return 200 when queried with a post request containing a valid tweet', function ( done ) {
    this.timeout(7000);
    var tweets = {
      tweet: "test" + uuid.v4()
    };

    apiHelper('post', uri, 200, tweets, function(err, res, body){
      expect(err).to.not.exist;
      tid = body.id;

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make async function work you should call `stopServer(done);` inside `client.post` callback. So your `after` function will become:

```
after(function(done) { 
    client.post('statuses/destroy/:id', {id: tid}, function(error, params, response){ 
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            done(error);
        } 
        stopServer(done);
    });
});
```